# Task status issue when using MySQL as result_backend in Celery

Tags: mysql, celery

Good day.

I am a beginner with Celery and I am having a hard time finding some solution to my problem.

My Celery App works fine when I am using Redis as the result backend.
I tried changing my result backend from Redis to MySQL. The task runs successfully while using MySQL as a result backend.

I have a monitoring task that checks the status of the tasks, but I noticed that when getting the task status it is always `PENDING`.

I checked the task status in the `celery_taskmeta` table and the task status there is `SUCCESS`.

Am I missing out on something when using MySQL as a result_backend?

I tried researching first before asking here but I can't find anything :(

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If the mysql table holds the correct task status values, then you monitoring task is pulling the data either from the wrong place or incorrectly.

Comment: Hi, @Shadow thanks for answering, how do I check that I am getting that the correct task status?
Is this issue related to setting the result_backend?

Comment: @Shadow, I saw the issue. I am pulling the data from the wrong place. Thanks for the help :)